# How can I find all points between point1 and point 2 - Objective c?

Tags: objective-c, math, cgpoint

I have two point like point `P1=(1,1)` And `P2=(5,5)` now i want to get all point when i draw a line between P1 and P2. Pragmatically in objective C like output is `(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4)(5,5)`

Comment: And what code you have written?

Comment: You may be interested in [Bresenham's line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm).

Comment: All points? What about `(1.34, 1.34)` and `(π, π)`?